# Best of Code Review 2016 - Diplomat category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2016 - Diplomat](/a/7108) category.

> *Tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer. Include a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post. Nominated answers must have a creation date in 2016. Downvotes don't count. Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nominating this [answer from Gareth Rees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144533/84718) to the question [Google Foobar Challenge: Lucky Triples](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144510/84718) for the lengthy details and teaching nature of an answer that boils down to "your code doesn't work as expected, try this instead".